# Host Microservices on Azure without Kubernetes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microservices

I want to host microservices on Azure platform.
But my Customer don't want to use AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service).

So Anyone have idea for same? Is there any other proper way for hosting microservices on azure?

Please guide me.

Comment: There's a lot in Azure. ContainerApps, ServiceFabric, Container Instances, Functions. It's not clear what you understand with Microservices.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview).

Comment: https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/x300/86355706/no-aks-containerapps-bonjour.jpg ;-)

Comment: I want to store data in Azure but not on Azure Storage. Well you can use SQL, Cosmos, MySql. Great, but it will still end up on Azure Storage.

AKS is abstracted away in ACA and might be subject for replacement down the line. Point is, it's not AKS.

Comment: Will it be feasible for handling nearly 3000 thousand requests per second?

Comment: It should without problems. But it's of course depending on how much processing that needs to take place on each request. In ACA you can scale out to 30 replicas (compare with kubernetes pods) and each replica can not be larger than 2 vCores and 4 GiB of RAM. If the size requirements are ok, then the platform should be able to handle a lot more requests than 3k per second. 

But note that you don't have the flexibility here to define your hardware. I.e. if you need GPUs, ACA is not for this workload.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are running your micro services in a Docker container. The other ways to run container apps in azure are:

- Azure App Service
- Run Docker on an Azure VM

Probably the Azure App Service is the best place to start.

Comment: Azure Container Services has been deprecated for a while

Comment: Let me check with Azure App service. But will it be feasible for handling nearly 3000 thousand requests per second?

Comment: Azure app service can both scale up and out, so it can handle as many requests as you provision hardware for (assuming there is no locking problems in the application) See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/app-service-scale-up-scale-out/